# Wildfly10 EAR Deployment fails from eclipse but works from standalone.bat

Tags: java, deployment, migration, wildfly, ejb-3.0

I've been working on a migration process of **Enterprise ARchive EAR** from **WebLogic** to **Wildfly 10**.

The app is composed of multiple layers listed down below :

```
***app-commun
***app-dao
***app-domain
***app-ear
***app-ejb
***app-manager
***app-parent
***app-service
***app-web
```

Here are the dependencies of every layer based on each's pom configuration:

```
***app-dao
    ***app-commun       

***app-domain
    ***app-commun

***app-ejb
    ***app-service
    ***app-commun
    ***app-dao

***app-manager
    ***app-domaine

***app-service
    ***app-manager
    ***app-dao
```

The EAR contains three components: **2 wars and app-ejb.jar**.

The migration was a bit long but successful.

**Steps of migration :**

Migrating from **JAVA 6 to JAVA 8**

Migrating from **EJB 2 to EJB 3**

At deployment stage, we tried to deploy it directley after generating the **EAR**
in the **deployments** directory of **Wildfly** and it worked like charm, but for some maintainance reasons we were under the obligation of deploying through eclipse famous **run on server** button, and it keeps crashing at the same place during the deployment process.

Exception trace :

```
                15:35:57,173 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."***-ear-13.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."***-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."***-ear-13.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."***-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "***-ejb.jar" of deployment "***-ear-13.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
                    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
                    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
                    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class ***.***.***.app.service.persistence.PersistenceDonneesMIFSMBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.***-ear-13.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.***-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
                    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
                    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
                    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
                    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
                    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
                    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
                    ... 5 more
                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ***/***/***/commun/exception/metier/BusinessException
                    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
                    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
                    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
                    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
                    ... 10 more
                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ***.***.***.commun.exception.metier.BusinessException from [Module "deployment.***-ear-13.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.***-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
                    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
                    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
                    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
                    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
                    ... 15 more
```

I tried to lookup for some possible causes by updating the 
**standalone-full.xml** **java:ee subsytem** by adding the following property

```
 <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
```

The classes claimed not to be found exist on the classpath yet i have no idea why 
i keep getting the same exception.

helps will be appreciated

Comment: Are you using JBoss Tools? It sounds like Eclipse might just be building the deployment incorrectly.

Comment: The eclipse version i use comes packed with jboss-tools, **eclipse-neon**